# Your way to write simple comments

Tags: comments

How do you guys write comments on some simple code that you use just for yourself?

I mostly write JavaScript and PHP code, and I can't really feel like I found a nice way to write comments.

If I have a short line of code, I usually do this:

```
x = doThis(getSomeValueFromSomewhere());  // This is a short line of code
```

Which seems really nice I think, but it doesnt really works when the line gets a little longer or on multiple lines,

```
 // Dont really like this since it's not clear if it describes only line 1, or all lines.
 aLongerVariableName = (getSomeValueFromSomewhere() == "this is what I want") ? "true value" : "false value";
 x = doThis(aLongerVariableName);
```

So, how do you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(*
 * For blocks of comments that serve as important documentation
 * e.g descriptions of functions.
 *)
```

maybe reformatted as

```
 (* For blocks of comments thet serve as important documentation
  * e.g descriptions of functions. *)
```

And the // for short inline comments like you do.
Don't forget that Ctrl-/ is your friend ;-)

Answer (score 2):

One simple way to improve the comment / decomment blocks in javascript, that works very easy and fast while programming.

When you want to make a comment block in javascript you need to add this well known way:

```
/*
...
*/
```

So when you need to decomment you need to change the beginning /* and the end */, but I used like this:

```
/*
...
//*/
```

That way changing the beginning /* to //* you will decomment the whole block, only addning one character and without the need to search for the end of the comment.